# Creating a large grid of similar objects using SceneKit

Tags: ios, opengl, scenekit

I'm currently testing the feasibility of using SceneKit for a game I would like to make but having trouble figuring out how best to create a grid of many similar geometrical objects in SceneKit while maintaining acceptable performance. Here is what I would like to do:

1. Place hundreds of a geometric primitive, just an ordinary cube for now in a grid.
2. Apply various vertex and/or surface and/or fragment shaders to each cube. Some cubes may have the same shaders applied to them but in practice I would like to have at least tens of different shaders that I can apply to the cubes.
3. I would like to be able to zoom the camera out and view all of the cubes simultaneously while maintaining a smooth framerate.

I'm beginning with a grid of 25 cubes by 25 cubes. I have achieved good performance by building the grid in a loop using a single SCNBox object for the geometry, and setting the `shaderModifiers` property of the `firstMaterial` property. I add all 625 cubes to a node, then add the `flattenedClone()` of this node to my scene's root node. This means the entire scene can be rendered with just 1 draw call.

The problem with reusing the geometry, however, is that all cubes must use the same shaders. But if I create a new SCNBox for each cube (so that I can set the shaders individually for each cube) then I end up with a draw call being made for each cube, which is inefficient and performance will suffer quickly when more and more cubes are added to the scene. And if the geometry is anything more complex than a cube, performance is degraded severely.

Of course I could optimize and have any cubes that DO use the same shaders share the same geometry, add them to their own node and add the `flattenedClone()` of that node to the scene. But is there more that I can do to optimize in this case? Or am I better off looking for an alternative to SceneKit entirely?

Comment: Did you try on iOS 9 (with the metal renderer)? SceneKit should automatically batch draw calls that share the same geometry and material (i.e you don't need to flatten yourself in that case). See WWDC2015's asteroid example in the scenekit pres

Comment: I did not, but thanks for pointing that out. I'll look into it now.

Comment: @toyos does this optimisation work in iOS 10? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39819036/how-to-get-the-advantages-of-scenekits-level-editor-programatically

Comment: Hi @stackunderflow, I want to do the same thing! Can you share How did you create the grid? Thanks.